# Excel TEXTJOIN of INDEX MATCH unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, textjoin

I have a table with 3 columns of data A,B,C.
On column D I'm trying to use TEXTJOIN that ignore blanks (Columns B and C may be blanks) + unique values meaning no value from the 3 results that were joined is the same.
[image: please see this example to be clearer]

Comment: Do you have Office 365 or is it 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER($F$2:$F$4,ISNUMBER(MATCH($E$2:$E$4,A2:C2,0)),"")))
```